# What happened to my chat on my PS3?

Tags: ps3, psn, ps4

Recently, I've been able to send messages to my friend who has a PlayStation 4. Sending messages works fine but we couldn't get voice chat to work. We were both online and everything was set up. Our microphone were working fine.

Is it because we were on different platforms that we couldn't voice chat or is it something got to do with our internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

[PS3 cannot voice or video chat with PS4](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2013/10/30/ps4-the-ultimate-faq-north-america/#sect4).

> **Can PS3 and PS4 users voice chat, or video chat together?**
>
> PS3 and PS4 users will be able to communicate with each other [using] text messages, but not video or voice chat.

That's why it didn't work for you - it doesn't work for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

**The previous answer explains exactly what the cause is, but to expand on it:**

PS3 and PS4, although they both run on the say platform in general, the use of servers is different causing the compatibility between them both to not work. It is the same as the Xbox 360 and the Xbox One, although the same platform, initial servers are different and therefore your only option of communication with friends on 'Next Gen' consoles is through text messages, simply because text messages are of simplest form and can transmit through any console, so it wouldn't surprise me if PS3 could message users on PS7 if both were still running.

However when it comes to sending Voice Messages or Video Messages it follows the same knowledge of downloading a video (MP4) and converting it into just the audio (MP3) and text messaging is even lower. ( just helping you understand :D ).

This means that Audio and Video carry additional files behind them, for example, if you were to save a written essay on Word you may find it to only consist of 88KB, however if you throw a few images or videos into the document it would reach MB's in seconds. It is because of these files that allow consoles to read what it is that makes the 2 consoles incompatible with eachother. Because you'd be very surprised at how much complexity is behind, to you, simply sending a voice message.

**In Brief: Don't read this, read the one above...**